# "Component for growth" or "Component of growth"?

Tags: grammar

"Gaining funding is a key component for growth"

"Gaining funding is a key component of growth"

Which is correct? If they are both fine, which is better?

Thanks!

Comment: They mean different things. You'll need to provide more context for us to know what the intended meaning is.

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatically correct, but I believe there are subtle differences that may make be relevant in this context.

*for* in this case has the meaning *in support of*, where *component of growth* means it is simply one of the elements included therein.

Since the sentence describes growth as a desirable objective, I think *for growth* makes the stronger statement.